# Recovering Stack Overflow for forgotten associated e-mail

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I forgot my stack overflow account, so i create new account just to ask how i can recover or merge my old account..

I have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge
but there are no response from the admins..

My old account is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220088/kiswono-prayogo
which i forgot which openid or email did i have used to logged in

My new account is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620210/kiswono-prayogo
which I have associate all my gmail account to it

any suggestion? on how i can merge or recover my old account?

so.. can stackoverflow create a better account recovery by not make user inputting their e-mail, but using a button on users page that sends an e-mail to it's associated account instead?

Comment: well.. no response =_=|||

Comment: ah, it was recently merged, thanks stackoverflow admin~ ^^

Comment: I have the same issue where I forgot the email for my old account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/803641/italics. I wanted to merge it with my new account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1066534/italics

Comment: i guess you should make a new (your own) question instead.. and don't forget to tag it with "support" and "merge-accounts"

Answer (score 0):

goto Profile page -> click my logins (on top right)-> add your merge account email-id.

Very simple to merge the multiple accounts this way.